# Difference in starting a SparkSession

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am relatively new to Spark, but I can see both methods start a spark session. Can someone kindly highlight the difference and limitations of starting a spark session in both these methods? And why is there two ways to do this?

And the other method is

And here are the codes:

```
# Find path to PySpark.
import collections
import findspark
findspark.init()

# Import PySpark and initialize SparkContext object.
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("RatingsHistogram")
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf = conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)

print('The Spark Version used is "{0}"\n\
The python version used is "{1}"\n\
The default parallelism is "{2}"\n\
The default number of partitions is "{3}"'.format(sc.version,sc.pythonVer,sc.defaultParallelism,sc.defaultMinPartitions))
```

And the other code is

```
# Find path to PySpark.
import collections
import findspark
findspark.init()

# Import PySpark and initialize SparkContext object.
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Basics').getOrCreate()
print(spark.version)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference very thin and subtle.

1. SparkContext Approach allows you to create plain sparksession. You can't interact with other APIs directly. If you want to interact with other APIs you have to create different contexts.
2. With SessionBuilder approach you can directly interact with Hive, Spark Streaming as all the APIs are integrated with it. One don't need to create different contexts for each API.

Please refer [Spark Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/sql-programming-guide.html#starting-point-sparksession)

Please refer [SparkContext vs SparkSession](http://data-flair.training/forums/topic/sparksession-vs-sparkcontext-in-apache-spark)

Comment: I agree with you. I have added few more inputs to my answer. If you found it helpful, you may accept the answer!

Comment: definetely answered the question in a clearing way, it would be nice to expand on your answer and add more resources so more people find it beneficialm thank you !